# Loading large dataset results in Connection refused

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to load a large dataset (750 GB) into Skyrise. For this I use

```
copy LINEITEM from 's3://myBucket/' 
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=key;aws_secret_access_key=secret'
null as '\000'
DELIMITER ','
region 'us-east-1'
ESCAPE;
```

After about 10 minutes I get

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to <some IP> failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I am able to load other datasets. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that your connection was dropped due a timeout. Please review the following document for steps to correct this issue:

["Troubleshooting connection issues in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/troubleshooting-connections.html)